# How to hide/show Stack panel in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

In a MVVM scenario, I want to show/hide a user control based on a hyper link click or image click. How can this be achieved in XAML?

Comment: [Databind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) the [`Visibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=vs.95).aspx) property to boolean property on your VM using a `BoolToVisibiltyConverter`

Comment: No need to define a property on the ViewModel here, in my opinion. See my answer for how to do it in XAML only.

Comment: @mark, I could not see your link

Comment: @SNS There is no link, I posted an answer to your question...

Answer (score 19):

Use a toggle button and bind the visibility of your `UserControl` using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

Define a resource:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
```

The toggle button:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="VisibilityToggle>
    <Image Source="..." />
</ToggleButton>
```

The user control:

```
<MyControl Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=VisibilityToggle, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Guys. it worked. I would like to change the toggle button apperance with styles. is it possible

Comment: Of course, you can style the ToggleButton like any other control. If the answer solved the problem, you can accept it and upvote all other answers that helped to solve the problem...

Answer (score 6):

Bind the `Visibility` property to a bool property of the ViewModel, using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

...

<MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding IsMyUserControlVisible, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private bool _isMyUserControlVisible;
public bool IsMyUserControlVisible
{
    get { return _isMyUserControlVisible; }
    set
    {
        _isMyUserControlVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsMyUserControlVisible");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a boolean property in your ViewModel that determines whether or not to show the control

```
public bool DisplayControl { get; set; }
```

Bind the visibiilty of your `StackPanel` using a `BooleanToVisibiltyConverter`

```
<Window.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And your control:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding DisplayControl, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I didn't mention the `INotifyPropertyChanged` which you'll have to use in the setter of `DisplayProperty` in order to update the view everytime the data changes.